# EX command not working in While Read loop in UNIX

Tags: unix

I am getting the following error when doing ex command inside while read line loop.

> 'syntax error: unexpected end of file'

Here is sample code:

```
    while IFS= read -r var
    do
    ex file1 << END
    command
    END
    done < "file.txt"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there whitespace in front of `END`?

Comment: there is one single space between << and END

Comment: The second heredoc marker must begin in the first column.  Or use `<<-`

Comment: `<<-` worked. Cheers!